# How do I search for an answer by a particular user

Tags: support, search

Sometimes I remember that someone wrote a very nice answer to a question.  While I remember the author, I don't always remember the question asked.  Is there a way to search the site by focusing on the author's of answers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "Advanced Search Tips" tooltip is at right from the "Search" button on the search page:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/search

---

To search for **answers** by **tohecz** in the tag **[tex-core]** the query 
[`user:11002 is:answer [tex-core]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A11002+is%3Aanswer+%5Btex-core%5D) works. To find the correct user ID, either visit the profile of the user (and the ID is in the address), or look him [in the user panel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users).

Comment: Excellent.  Narrowed my search to three possibilities with the second one the one I was looking for.  Thank you!!!

Comment: So the problem of finding out the user id is left.